# Importing DOORS attributes enum change not recognized

Tags: ibm-doors

I'm working in a project, where I need to import some modified attributes from some existing template to my DOORS module.

New attributes are recognized and can be easily added to my module. However, some already existing attributes, that were in between modified in the template are not recognized during the import.

Basically, for this attribute the enumeration had been changed. I would expect doors to show this in the incompatible enumeration step of the import dialogue. However, this section was just skipped and I simply jump to the last step of the import.

Is this a known DOORS issue or am I doing something wrong here. I double checked, that the enumeration types in the template are really different to my module.

I was also surprised, that are very few attributes were recognized that are already the same among template and my DOORS module (Available types). This seems to be also not correct.

[image: DOORS Import dialogue for attributes]